# In Typescript Typewriter use project in different solution

Tags: asp.net, typescript, typewriter

I have a .NET application where UI project in a separate solution and API, Model projects together are in a separate solution. So, basically UI is completely decoupled from API project.
In my case, how to reference project name in the .tst file?

In UI project, I tried like this but it is not working as the projects (Model) is in a different solution.

```
using Typewriter.Extensions.Types;    
    Template(Settings settings)
    {
        settings.IncludeProject("Model");  
             
    }
```

Question:
How to refer projects in a different solution? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.